# Opera Aria is not working. How can I solve?

Tags: xaml, browser, opera

Aria worked until recently (Opera One(version: 104.0.4944.36 on Win10 22H2)), now I get the following blocking error; apparently there is no obvious solution:

Unexpected Application Error!
Unknown language: `xaml` is not registered
Error: Unknown language: `xaml` is not registered
at t (chrome-extension://igpdmclhhlcpoindmhkhillbfhdgoegm/aria.js:172:180184)
at Object.CI [as highlight] (chrome-extension://igpdmclhhlcpoindmhkhillbfhdgoegm/aria.js:172:180370)
at chrome-extension://igpdmclhhlcpoindmhkhillbfhdgoegm/aria.js:172:291138
at chrome-extension://igpdmclhhlcpoindmhkhillbfhdgoegm/aria.js:172:74467
...

Is it a known issue?

Comment: Now it is working..